# SwiftUIのonOpenURL(Deep Link)で渡されたURLを別画面に渡せない

Tags: swift, swiftui

onOpenURL(Deep Link)で渡されたURLを別画面(TimeLineView)に渡したいのですが、なぜかnilになってしまいます。

タイミング的には、値が入っているはずなのですが、nilになってしまい`Text("nothing")`が表示されてしまいます。

なぜか以下のコードを追加するとちゃんと値が渡されるようになります。

```swift
.onChange(of: url) { value in
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TwitterApp: App {
  @State var showTimeLineView:Bool = false
  @State var url: URL?
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .onOpenURL { url in
          self.url = url
          showTimeLineView.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showTimeLineView) {
          if let url = url {
            TimeLineView(url: url)
          } else {
            Text("nothing")
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: もしかしたらsheet(item)でうまくいくかもしれないです。
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336892/why-does-my-sheet-open-before-my-data-is-set

Comment: sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)でも動作が確認できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在のSwiftUI実装では、`sheet`などに渡すクロージャー内で`@State`変数をキャプチャしている場合、それらの`@State`変数が期待通りに動かないと言う問題点が報告されています。

ご自身で見つけられたように、`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`なんかを使うのも一つの解決方法ですが、`sheet`で表示したい内容を別Viewにして、`@Binding`を渡すと言う方法でも解消できることが知られています。

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct OnOpenURLToSheetApp: App {
    @State var showTimeLineView:Bool = false
    @State var url: URL?
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    self.url = url
                    showTimeLineView.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showTimeLineView) {
                    MySheet(url: $url)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MySheet: View {
    @Binding var url: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let url = url {
            TimeLineView(url: url)
        } else {
            Text("nothing")
        }
    }
}
```

お試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`@State`を引数に使う場合は注意が必要なんですね。
確かに`@State`で宣言しているので、`@Binding`で渡すのが普通?ですね。

帰宅後自分のコメントも含めて試してみます。

Comment: 動作を確認できました。

Comment: @zunda さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。是非`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`を使った方も自己回答として投稿して見てください。